# How to use ctrl + click to show super or implementation methods in Intellij Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea

In Intellij Idea, I should use CTRL + ALT + B to turn into implementation method, use CTRL + U to turn into super method, it's not convenient and not easy to remember so many shortcut keys, so how to use CTRL + click to forward that like in Eclipse??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your key map in intellij-idea exactly like ECLIPSE by following steps.
Move to File -> Settings -> Keymap and change Keymaps settings to your keymap,for Example : ECLIPSE,so that you can use the short cut keys like in ECLIPSE.

[image]

Comment: You can set your shortcut here [John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8275347/john-chou) This CTRL+ click works in this keymap.

Comment: If so, the Ctrl + click default to facade method will be overrided.